# xamarin forms: views and list views in the same page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms page, I want to display a chart(sync fusion) and a list view on the same page. Is it possible?

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>

        <chart:SfChart x:Name="Chart" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <chart:SfChart.BindingContext>
      <local:ReportPageViewModel/>
    </chart:SfChart.BindingContext>

    <chart:SfChart.Legend>
      <chart:ChartLegend />
    </chart:SfChart.Legend>

    <chart:SfChart.Title>
      <chart:ChartTitle Text="Chart"/>
    </chart:SfChart.Title>

   <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
      <chart:CategoryAxis LabelRotationAngle="-45" >
        <chart:CategoryAxis.Title>
          <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Name"/>
        </chart:CategoryAxis.Title>
      </chart:CategoryAxis>
    </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

     <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
      <chart:NumericalAxis>
        <chart:NumericalAxis.Title>
          <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Height (in cm)"/>
        </chart:NumericalAxis.Title>
      </chart:NumericalAxis>
    </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

   <chart:SfChart.Series>
      <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Label="Heights" XBindingPath="Name" YBindingPath="Height" EnableTooltip="True">
        <chart:ColumnSeries.DataMarker>
          <chart:ChartDataMarker/>
        </chart:ColumnSeries.DataMarker>
      </chart:ColumnSeries>
    </chart:SfChart.Series>
  </chart:SfChart>
    <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type Cell}">
            <EntryCell Text="{Binding Phone}" />
            <EntryCell Text="{Binding Code}" />
            <TextCell Text="LOGIN" Command="{Binding Login}"/>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
  </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This results in displaying only the list view but not the chart. Is it possible to accommodate list view along with other views ?

Comment: yes, it's possible, but I don't think you should nest a ListView inside of a ScrollView.  You probably should set an explicit HeightRequest value on the ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason stated, using a ScrollView around a ListView is not the best approach, as it can cause many scrolling issues, because the ListView has its own scrolling mechanism.

One way to do this, is to put the Charts in the ListView Header.

```
// Add this to your page
x:Name="this"

// Use the HeaderTemplate
<ListView x:Name="listView" Header="{Binding this.BindingContext}">
   <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        ...
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.HeaderTemplate>     
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     ...
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What is 'this' ? for my current page how can I add chart over a list view?

Comment: "this" is just added to your page, e.g. <ContentPage x:Name="this" ...   It is what the Header uses to Bind to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I was looking for one solution.

I wanted a Picker above my Chart and put the elements into a Grid was the solution in the next way:

```
 <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Picker x:Name="Picker" Grid.Row="0"/>

             <chart:SfChart Grid.Row="1" >
               My chart...
             </chart:SfChart>
       </Grid>
 </ScrollView>
```

and it looks like the next images
[Picker above the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy4C8.png)

Using the picker

[Using the picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPC8l.png)